# How do I get strings from a JSON file?

Tags: json, gettext, xgettext

I'm writing a internationalized desktop program written in Vala where a use an [extern JSON file](https://github.com/chavaone/gnomecat/blob/master/data/languages.json) to store a list of languages.

I'm using gettext for l10n so if I get the string from the json file and I do something like `_(string_var)` I could get the translated string. The problem is that I don't know how can I add the string to the pot file using xgettext or some similar tool.

Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I finally use was to modify the JSON file to use double quoted strings only when I wanted to translate that string. For example:

```
{
    'code' : 'es',
    'name' : "Spanish; Castilian",
    'pluralform' : 'nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);',
    'default-team-email': 'gnome-es-list@gnome.org'
}
```

In the previous piece of JSON file the only string I wanted to translate was *"Spanish; Castillian"*. Then in the POTFILES.in, I just use the [gettext/quoted](http://linux.die.net/man/8/intltool-extract) type.

```
# List of source files containing translatable strings.
# Please keep this file sorted alphabetically.
[encoding: UTF-8]
[type: gettext/quoted]data/languages.json
[type: gettext/quoted]data/plurals.json
[type: gettext/glade]data/ui/appmenu.ui

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tool jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is an option for you, below might work;

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chavaone/gnomecat/master/data/languages.json | jq .languages[43].name
"English"
```

Comment: Umm, I guess that some script using that tool could works. But I was thinking in a solution similar to the one I use with XML ui files where the string fetch it's is made automatically by gettext or intltool. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned that I'm writing a desktop program :S